# Artificial Intelligence: Time Complexity of NBA* Search

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am studying informed search algorithms, and for New Bidirectional A* Search, I know that the space complexity is O(b^d), where d is the depth of the shallowest goal node and b is the branch factor. I have tried to find out what its time complexity is, but I haven't been able to find any exact information about it on online resources. Is the exact time complexity of NBA* Search unknown and what is the difference between the original Bidirectional A*? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific models of your problem (eg uniformly growing graph in both directions with unit edge costs and the number of states growing exponentially) then most bidirectional search algorithms require O(b^(d/2)) node expansions and require O(b^(d/2)) time. But, this simple model doesn't actual model most real-world problems.

Given this, I would not recommend putting significant effort into studying New Bidirectional A*.

The state of the art in bidirectional search has changed massively in the last few years. The current algorithm with the best theoretical guarantees is [NBS - Near-Optimal Bidirectional Search](https://www.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/papers/chen2017nbs.pdf). The algorithm finds optimal paths and is near-optimal in node-expansions. That is, NBS is guaranteed to do no more than 2x more necessary expansions than the *best possible algorithm* (given reasonable theoretical assumptions such as using the same heuristic). All other algorithms (including A*) can do arbitrarily worse than NBS.

Other algorithm variants of NBS, such as [DVCBS](https://www.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/papers/DVCBS.pdf), have been proposed which follow the same basic structure, do not have the same guarantees, but perform well in practice.